# Fixing Tukey multicomparison

Tags: r, visualization, stat, posthoc, tukey

Hi I was running a Tukey multicomparison test for the data below (data and code attached) after confirming that the data was normal, equal variances and significant interactions via two-way ANOVA (time and growth condition). The results in R and final barchart ([1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LIaY2.png)) were included as well. As you can see the visualization could be improved and need to be tidied up due to the redundant letters. I was advised to redo using the same Tukey test but adding some additional codes to assign the samples at time point 0 hr as the reference/control (sort of like Dunnett test with a single control). I couldn't really find any useful information regarding this online, would appreciate any help/suggestion!

```
    data.frame(Exp1)
   id   growth_condition time   fv   fq  npq in_situ    rd
1   1            Control    0 0.81 0.56 0.72   0.797 1.000
2   2            Control    0 0.81 0.58 0.78   0.788 1.000
3   3            Control    0 0.80 0.59 0.76   0.793 1.000
4   4 High light+Chilled    0 0.82 0.57 0.85   0.799 1.000
5   5 High light+Chilled    0 0.81 0.59 0.75   0.796 1.000
6   6 High light+Chilled    0 0.81 0.56 0.69   0.782 1.000
7   7            Control  0.5 0.81 0.53 1.08   0.759 1.279
8   8            Control  0.5 0.81 0.56 0.72   0.759 0.668
9   9            Control  0.5 0.79 0.50 1.04   0.771 0.877
10 10 High light+Chilled  0.5 0.70 0.46 1.04   0.540 0.487
11 11 High light+Chilled  0.5 0.60 0.43 0.69   0.652 1.341
12 12 High light+Chilled  0.5 0.73 0.46 1.19   0.606 0.904
13 13            Control    8 0.82 0.52 1.20   0.753 0.958
14 14            Control    8 0.81 0.55 1.09   0.759 0.642
15 15            Control    8 0.80 0.55 1.07   0.747 0.612
16 16 High light+Chilled    8 0.44 0.28 0.58   0.230 0.471
17 17 High light+Chilled    8 0.35 0.21 0.45   0.237 0.777
18 18 High light+Chilled    8 0.54 0.35 0.68   0.186 0.342
19 19            Control   24 0.81 0.49 1.17   0.762 0.915
20 20            Control   24 0.82 0.67 1.25   0.749 0.876
21 21            Control   24 0.82 0.48 1.18   0.756 0.836
22 22 High light+Chilled   24 0.40 0.25 0.45   0.089 0.392
23 23 High light+Chilled   24 0.43 0.27 0.51   0.106 0.627
24 24 High light+Chilled   24 0.34 0.21 0.37   0.140 0.258
25 25            Control   48 0.81 0.48 1.05   0.773 0.662
26 26            Control   48 0.80 0.45 1.14   0.785 0.914
27 27            Control   48 0.82 0.47 1.09   0.792 0.912
28 28 High light+Chilled   48 0.73 0.45 0.90   0.750 0.800
29 29 High light+Chilled   48 0.70 0.51 0.79   0.626 1.305
30 30 High light+Chilled   48 0.66 0.43 0.74   0.655 0.579
```

Code:

```
res.Exp8 <- aov(npq ~ growth_condition * time, data =Exp1)
summary(res.Exp8)

t8<-TukeyHSD(res.Exp8)
plot(t8)
multcompLetters4(res.Exp8,t8)
```

Results:

```
$`growth_condition:time`
            Control:24              Control:8             Control:48 High light+Chilled:0.5            Control:0.5  High light+Chilled:48 
                   "a"                   "ab"                  "abc"                  "abc"                  "abc"                  "bcd" 
  High light+Chilled:0              Control:0   High light+Chilled:8  High light+Chilled:24 
                 "cde"                  "cde"                   "de"                    "e"
```

Comment: I'm not sure I'm getting your point. You'd like to reshape the output of Tukey so the letters would be the one in green ? If so the results would be wrong. For example, switching the groupe "de" to "a" introduce an error, because the group "e" would then be different to all others groups. Also, please look at the dput() function to facilitate our manipulation of your data. (Basically, just write dput(yourdataframe) in R, an copy here the output.

Comment: @Beeflight31Nope they shouldn't be identical, those in green are just an idea of what we would be expecting, I'd like to generate a similar plot but with better comparison/visualisation, ideally with 1/2 letter instead of 3 letters in the original plot. The latter is essentially not wrong, but my lecturer would like to improve the visualisation, hence I was asked to re-run the similar multicomparison using the same data with Tukey test but this time include a reference/control (control in 0 hr), similar to Dunnet test in one-way anova, hopefully I'd be able to get 1/2 multicomp letters.